# Get variable from one Screen Class into another (KivyMD issue)

Tags: python, kivy

I'm building a KivyMD application, but I'm having some issues to get a variable defined in one Screen class into another. See my script below:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp, Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from api import gen_5_images

# --- this changes the app's default background --- #
Window.clearcolor = (.9, .9, .9, 1)
Window.size = (400, 500)

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    source = StringProperty()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs): 
        super(HomeScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text = 'dog'

    def get_text(self):
        self.text = self.ids.input.text
        return self.text

class ResultsScreen(HomeScreen):
    source = StringProperty()
    def on_manager(self, *args):
        # gets run when manager property is changed
        self.urls = gen_5_images(self.manager.get_screen('home').text)
        self.source = self.urls[0]
        
class Main(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file("layout.kv")
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='home'))
        sm.add_widget(ResultsScreen(name='results'))
        return sm

Main().run()
```

When I switch from HomeScreen to ResultsScreen, I get the variable "dog" (defined in HomeScreen's **init**) as text, and I want the output of the "get_text" function instead.

See below my .kv file:

```
#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
<HomeScreen>:
    name: 'home'
    MDFloatLayout:
        md_bg_color: hex('#003153') # background color
        MDLabel:
            text: "DreamGen"
            color: hex('#f5deb3')
            halign: "center"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .9}
            font_size: "40sp"
            font_name: "Pacifico"
        MDTextField:
            id: input
            hint_text: "I had a dream..."
            hint_text_color_normal: hex("#00aae4")
            hint_text_color_focus: hex("#00aae4")
            helper_text_color_focus: hex("#00aae4")
            line_color_normal: hex('#003153') #make line color of background
            line_color_focus: hex('#003153') #make line color of background
            helper_text: "Write what comes to your mind"
            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
            text_color_focus: hex('#add8e6') # color of text clicked
            text_color_normal: hex('#add8e6') # color of text without clicked
            mode: "rectangle"
            multiline: True
            size_hint_x: 0.7
            size_hint_y: 0.5
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            text: "Generate"
            text_color: hex('#003153')
            md_bg_color: hex('#add8e6')
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .1}
            font_size: "15sp"
            on_release: 
                root.get_text()
                root.manager.current = "results"

<ResultsScreen>:
    name: 'results'
    MDFloatLayout:
        md_bg_color: hex('#003153') # background color
        MDLabel:
            text: "DreamGen"
            color: hex('#f5deb3')
            halign: "center"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .9}
            font_size: "40sp"
            font_name: "Pacifico"
        AsyncImage:
            size_hint: None,None
            size: root.height, root.height
            source: root.source
            mipmap: True
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            text: "Try again!"
            text_color: hex('#003153')
            md_bg_color: hex('#add8e6')
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .1}
            font_size: "15sp"
            on_release: root.manager.current = "home"
```

If someone can help me, I would very much appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
self.urls = gen_5_images(HomeScreen().text)
```

is creating a new instance of `HomeScreen` and accessing the `text` variable of that new instance. That new instance of `HomeScreen` is not the instance that is used in your GUI. To access the correct instance of `HomeScreen`, try changing that code to:

```
self.urls = gen_5_images(self.manager.get_screen('home').text)
```

Oops, that code will work, but not in the `__init__()` method, since the `manager` property is not yet set at that time. You can handle that by waiting until the `manager` property is set. Try replacing:

```
class ResultsScreen(HomeScreen):
    source = StringProperty()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.urls = gen_5_images(HomeScreen().text)
        self.source = self.urls[0]
```

with:

```
class ResultsScreen(HomeScreen):
    source = StringProperty()

    # def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    #     super().__init__()
    #     # self.urls = gen_5_images(HomeScreen().text)
    #     # self.source = self.urls[0]

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        # gets run each time this Screen is displayed
        self.urls = gen_5_images(self.manager.get_screen('home').text)
        self.source = self.urls[0]
```

Comment: Hi thank you john. I get the following error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_screen'

Comment: Much appreciated John! I believe we are almost there, but it is still returning "dog" instead of the new variable defined on "get_text()". I'll make the necessary changes to the initial question, with your tips already integrated.

Comment: After pondering your code, I believe that you need to have the code that was originally in the `__init__()` method, then in the `on_manager()` method to be run whenever the `ResultsScreen` is displayed. See my again updated answer

Comment: It's amazing John it worked! I didn't know there was a difference between "on_manager()" and "on_enter()" functions. I need to go deeper on KivyMD documentation. Maybe you know any books? Thank you very much!